# Java package error in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I get this error in my project which I imported from my backup. Before I could run the project without issue in eclipse. I formatted my machine and now when I try to run the application I get this error. what could it be..

[image]

I am not using maven and I tried to remove the jars and adding them all back....
One thing that differs from my previous setting is that i was using java sdk 1.6.22 version before now i am using java 1.8

Comment: The required JAR might not be in your build path.  If you are using Maven, check that the dependencies are updated and then Clean the project.

Comment: You should not be using `sun.*` packages in your code. `sun.*` and `com.sun.*` are internal packages of the JDK, not part of the public API. As far as I know there is a mechanism (since Java 7 or 8) that hides these packages.

Comment: As already mentioned you should not be using any `sun.*` packages as they are internal. It looks like this one has been moved in Java 8

Answer (score 0):

You are missing reference to the JAR file after you formatted your PC.

You put your JAR file again in classpath, and error will go off.

Comment: That class was part of the JDK until java 7

Answer (score 0):

You have lost the reference to the jar.

Here you are two possible solutions:

- If you are using **Maven**, check your `pom.xml` and then if all it's
  correct make an `Maven > Update Maven Project`.
- If you are adding directly the jars to the `Buildpath`, add again and
  the error will dissapear.

Comment: That class was part of the JDK until java 7

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

1. There is no sun.utils.LocaleServiceProviderPool, at least not in the packages provided directly by the JDK (at least checked on my machine with JDK8 installed).
   Maybe you mean sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleServiceProviderPool?
2. As stated before, the use of sun.* packages is not encouraged since they are internal API.